# Can't install 'ihaskell-diagrams' using Cabal

Tags: haskell, glib, cabal-install, ihaskell

When I try to

```
cabal install ihaskell-diagrams
```

I get the error

> The pkg-config package 'glib-2.0' is required but it could not be
>   found.

What is `glib` and how do I install it so that it is available for Cabal?

---

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cairo-0.13.1.0...
Configuring glib-0.13.2.1...
Failed to install cairo-0.13.1.0
Build log ( /Users/Rax/.cabal/logs/cairo-0.13.1.0.log ):
[1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     ( /var/folders/b6/3rk65h797p7407x7d36sqn9c0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-57646/cairo-0.13.1.0/SetupWrapper.hs, /var/folders/b6/3rk65h797p7407x7d36sqn9c0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-57646/cairo-0.13.1.0/dist/setup/SetupWrapper.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/b6/3rk65h797p7407x7d36sqn9c0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-57646/cairo-0.13.1.0/dist/setup/setup.hs, /var/folders/b6/3rk65h797p7407x7d36sqn9c0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-57646/cairo-0.13.1.0/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /var/folders/b6/3rk65h797p7407x7d36sqn9c0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-57646/cairo-0.13.1.0/dist/setup/setup ...
[1 of 2] Compiling Gtk2HsSetup      ( Gtk2HsSetup.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Gtk2HsSetup.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( SetupMain.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Main.o )
Linking dist/setup-wrapper/setup ...
Configuring cairo-0.13.1.0...
setup: The pkg-config package 'cairo' version >=1.2.0 is required but it could
not be found.
Failed to install glib-0.13.2.1
Build log ( /Users/Rax/.cabal/logs/glib-0.13.2.1.log ):
[1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     ( /var/folders/b6/3rk65h797p7407x7d36sqn9c0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-57647/glib-0.13.2.1/SetupWrapper.hs, /var/folders/b6/3rk65h797p7407x7d36sqn9c0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-57647/glib-0.13.2.1/dist/setup/SetupWrapper.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/b6/3rk65h797p7407x7d36sqn9c0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-57647/glib-0.13.2.1/dist/setup/setup.hs, /var/folders/b6/3rk65h797p7407x7d36sqn9c0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-57647/glib-0.13.2.1/dist/setup/Main.o )

Linking /var/folders/b6/3rk65h797p7407x7d36sqn9c0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-57647/glib-0.13.2.1/dist/setup/setup ...
[1 of 2] Compiling Gtk2HsSetup      ( Gtk2HsSetup.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Gtk2HsSetup.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( SetupMain.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Main.o )
Linking dist/setup-wrapper/setup ...
Configuring glib-0.13.2.1...
setup: The pkg-config package 'glib-2.0' is required but it could not be
found.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cairo-0.13.1.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
diagrams-cairo-1.3.0.5 depends on glib-0.13.2.1 which failed to install.
glib-0.13.2.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
ihaskell-diagrams-0.3.1.0 depends on glib-0.13.2.1 which failed to install.
pango-0.13.1.0 depends on glib-0.13.2.1 which failed to install.
```

Comment: *gilb*  and *cairo* are part of the GTK+ toolkit; as that is a non-Haskell dependency you need to install it in your system separately (I don't know what is the most convenient way of doing that in OSX).

Comment: On OS X you can install it using homebrew

Comment: I don't understand why this question got downvoted.

Comment: Because the author obviously didn't even attempt to do any research on their own.  A simple Google search for "glib" would have told them what it is, and "glib osx" would have told them how to install it on OS X (the second result for me is a SO post which suggests `brew install glib`).

Comment: @nemequ: My bad. The searches I did (obviously not?) do — "haskell glib", "cabal glib", etc. — yielded no useful (and sometimes confusing) results.

Comment: There are [detailed instructions for installing Gtk2Hs](https://wiki.haskell.org/Gtk2Hs/Installation), including a page [specifically devoted to OSX](https://wiki.haskell.org/Gtk2Hs/Mac).

Comment: @DanielWagner: That would make an accepted answer if elaborated a bit.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I won't do that, because I don't have a Mac and I can't verify what's actually worked for me. But it's perfectly good etiquette to answer your own question once you've discovered something that works -- so I say write up the answer you'd accept, and accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion here results from the perhaps unclear error message: the missing components are *not* Cabal packages, but libraries that need to be separately installed.

Some of these libraries have their own dependencies, or installing them may reveal additional missing packages, so that the specific requirements on your system my be different; but in general, when you get an error that a "pig-config package" is missing, you will need to install it with your package manager (not Cabal).

For example,

```
brew install glib
brew install cairo
brew install pango
```

work for me and allow me to

```
cabal install ihaskell-diagrams
```

without further errors.